# Why would a php file return 404 while in the bin directory on IIS7?

Tags: php, iis7

I'm running IIS7 and I have fastCGI installed and php code works just fine normally.

Today I added a php file that contained only code an no html markup to the bin directory. And when I try to access it via http, i get a 404 back.

I've verified the file is on the server, and I've verified that the problem goes away if I move the file out of the bin directory.

My question is why does the bin directory hide php files? (and html files too, incidentally.) Is it some IIS security precaution?

thanks.

Comment: You'll be better of posting this on http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: If all (you mention PHP and HTML) files in the bin directory are being denied access via the HTTP protocol then it sounds like a security _feature_ set up on your (IIS) server.

Comment: @w3d that's what i was thinking, but would like to know more about the why. @John Conde thanks. done: http://serverfault.com/questions/191070/why-would-a-php-file-return-404-while-in-the-bin-directory-on-iis7

Comment: This is a security feature of IIS - mostly for ASP.NET sites, where the dlls are stored in a /bin directory off the main web site.